# Ajax request giving id NULL

Tags: laravel

Good Morning...I am trying to update the data in table using ajax, while passing the data to controller using id, ID preview is showing NULL and so not able to update the data in Table.
I am trying to add new data in one table and at same time update data in another table using same ajax...
Ajax -

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }

});

$(document).on('click', '#footer_addnewinspectiondata_button', function() {

    $.ajax({

        type: 'put',
        url: '/addbuffaloinspectiondata',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'buffaloID': $('#buffaloID').val(),
            'inspectiondate': $('#inspectiondate').val(),
            'pregnantstatus': $('#pregnantstatus').val(),
            'healthstatus': $('#healthstatus').val(),
            'weight': $('#weight').val(),
            'height': $('#height').val(),
            'weeklytika': $('#weeklytika').val(),
            'monthlytika': $('#monthlytika').val(),
            'inspection': $('#inspection').val(),
            'inspectionby': $('#inspectionby').val(),
            'inspectionnote': $('#inspectionnote').val(),

        },
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Web.php File

```
Route:: put('/addbuffaloinspectiondata', 
       [viewbuffaloController::class,'addbuffaloinspectiondata'])->name('addbuffaloinspectiondata');
```

Controller File -

```
public function addbuffaloinspectiondata(Request $req) 
{
    // add new data in buffaloinspection table for Buffalo ID

    $newdata = new buffaloinspectiondata;

    $newdata->buffaloID            = $req->buffaloID;
    $newdata->inspectiondate       = $req->inspectiondate;
   
    $newdata->weight               = $req->weight;
    $newdata->height               = $req->height;
    $newdata->pregnant             = $req->pregnantstatus;
    
    $newdata->health               = $req->healthstatus;
    $newdata->weeklytika           = $req->weeklytika;
    $newdata->monthlytika          = $req->monthlytika;
    
    $newdata->inspection           = $req->inspection;
    $newdata->inspectionby         = $req->inspectionby;
    $newdata->inspectionnote       = $req->inspectionnote;

    // update data in BuffaloDATA Table

    $updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);
    
        $updatedata->weight             = $req->get('weight');
        $updatedata->height             = $req->get('height');
    

        $newdata->save ();
        $updatedata->save ();

        return response()->json([$newdata,$updatedata],200);
}
```

Did i miss something or doing wrong in code... Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: `type: 'post',` can you please try with post method

Answer (score 0):

The Reason that you are getting Id NULL is ***dd($updatedata);*** it will stop execution after that
remove it

and change your return like this

`return response()->json([$newdata,$updatedata],200);`

your controller

```
public function addbuffaloinspectiondata(Request $req) 
{
    // add new data in buffaloinspection table for Buffalo ID

    $newdata = new buffaloinspectiondata();

    $newdata->buffaloID            = $req->buffaloID;
    $newdata->inspectiondate       = $req->inspectiondate;
   
    $newdata->weight               = $req->weight;
    $newdata->height               = $req->height;
    $newdata->pregnant             = $req->pregnantstatus;
    
    $newdata->health               = $req->healthstatus;
    $newdata->weeklytika           = $req->weeklytika;
    $newdata->monthlytika          = $req->monthlytika;
    
    $newdata->inspection           = $req->inspection;
    $newdata->inspectionby         = $req->inspectionby;
    $newdata->inspectionnote       = $req->inspectionnote;
    $newdata->save();

    // update data in BuffaloDATA Table

    $updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);
    $updatedata->weight  = $req->weight;
    $updatedata->height  = $req->height;
    $updatedata->update();

        
        

        return response()->json([$newdata,$updatedata],200);
}
```

Comment: ok... As i am new, can u explain what should i do.... Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: just remove ***dd($updatedata);*** or comment it out

Comment: Argument #2 ($status) must be of type int, null given,

Comment: I've updated the answer change your return

Comment: I updated my qus. error is - message: "Attempt to assign property \"weight\" on null"

Comment: I updated my answer fixed your controller

Comment: no luck..... Same error.... Just a though... Can i run 2 ajax ( one for Add new and One for Update) at same time with same button event... Really thankful for your reply....

Comment: Yes, you can do it with two ajax. but also it's much easier to do it with just one ajax

Comment: Just for checking. change your ajax type and route to Post test it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public function addbuffaloinspectiondata(Request $req)     
{
    // add or update operation.

    if(isset($req->buffaloID)){

        //buffalodata model
        $newdata = buffaloinspectiondata::find($req->buffaloID);

        //buffalodata model
        $updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);

        $updatedata->weight             = isset($req->get('weight'))? $req->get('weight') : 0 ;
        $updatedata->height             = isset($req->get('weight'))? $req->get('height') : 0 ;
        $updatedata->save ();

    }else{
        $newdata = new buffaloinspectiondata;
    }

    $newdata->buffaloID            = $req->buffaloID;
    $newdata->inspectiondate       = $req->inspectiondate;
    $newdata->weight               = isset($req->get('weight'))? $req->get('weight') : 0 ;
    $newdata->height               = isset($req->get('weight'))? $req->get('height') : 0 ;
    $newdata->pregnant             = $req->pregnantstatus;
    $newdata->health               = $req->healthstatus;
    $newdata->weeklytika           = $req->weeklytika;
    $newdata->monthlytika          = $req->monthlytika;
    $newdata->inspection           = $req->inspection;
    $newdata->inspectionby         = $req->inspectionby;
    $newdata->inspectionnote       = $req->inspectionnote;
    $newdata->save();

    return response()->json([$newdata,$updatedata],200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... But i want to update data and add data both in 2 different table..

Comment: can you please provide both table schema ?

Comment: added photo of scheme

Comment: Same error - ""Attempt to assign property \"weight\" on null".... If i remove the update data and keep only add new data, ajax run successfully and add new data in inspectiondata table... I think i mess up with update data in "buffalodata"

Comment: Please check updated answer.